UIncaught ReferenceError: db is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (VM586 editor.js:66:9)
I'm building a blog website using Firebase Firestore and JavaScript. I'm trying to save blog posts to Firestore, but I'm encountering an issue where db is not defined when I attempt to use it in my editor.js file.
Here’s a brief overview of what I’m trying to do:
User Interface: I have an input field for the blog title and a text area for the article content. There's also an option to upload an image for the banner, which gets displayed at the top of the blog post.
Publishing the Post: When the user clicks the "Publish" button, I want to generate a unique document ID, gather the input data, and store it in Firestore under a new document in the "blogs" collection.
Problem: Despite setting up Firebase and Firestore correctly (or so I think), when I try to use the db variable to interact with Firestore, I get a ReferenceError: db is not defined.
this is my editor.js
const blogTitleField = document.querySelector('.title');
const articleField = document.querySelector('.article');

// banner
const bannerImage = document.querySelector('#banner-upload');
const banner = document.querySelector(".banner");
let bannerPath;

const publishBtn = document.querySelector('.publish-btn');
const uploadInput = document.querySelector('#image-upload');

bannerImage.addEventListener('change', () => {
    uploadImage(bannerImage, "banner");
})

uploadInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
    uploadImage(uploadInput, "image");
})

const uploadImage = (uploadFile, uploadType) => {
    const [file] = uploadFile.files;
    if (file && file.type.includes("image")) {
        const formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append('image', file);

        fetch('/upload', {
            method: 'post',
            body: formdata
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (uploadType == "image") {
                    addImage(data, file.name);
                } else {
                    bannerPath = `${location.origin}/${data}`;
                    banner.style.backgroundImage = `url("${bannerPath}")`;
                }
            })
    } else {
        alert("upload Image only");
    }
}

const addImage = (imagePath, alt) => {
    let curPos = articleField.selectionStart;
    let textToInsert = `\r![${alt}](${imagePath})\r`;
    articleField.value = articleField.value.slice(0, curPos) + textToInsert + articleField.value.slice(curPos);
}

let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

publishBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (articleField.value.length && blogTitleField.value.length) {
        // generating id
        let letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        let blogTitle = blogTitleField.value.split(" ").join("-");
        let id = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            id += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
        }

        // setting up docName
        let docName = `${blogTitle}-${id}`;
        let date = new Date(); // for published at info

        //access Firestore with db variable;
        db.collection("blogs").doc(docName).set({
            title: blogTitleField.value,
            article: articleField.value,
            bannerImage: bannerPath,
            publishedAt: `${date.getDate()} ${months[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getFullYear()}`
        })
            .then(() => {
                location.href = `/${docName}`;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            })
    }
})

this is my firebase installation (firebase.jsm)
Can any one help me plzzz,
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDQaVM5xjFB-WB4IQXnupSvWOJSQdlrN00",
    authDomain: "bloggin-site-c4727.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "bloggin-site-c4727",
    storageBucket: "bloggin-site-c4727.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "170432646256",
    appId: "1:170432646256:web:f36807db85372e1956f8b5"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.firestore();

export { db };

In my HTML, I'm including the scripts like this:
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.13.0/firebase-app.mjs"\>\</script\>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.13.0/firebase-firestore.mjs"\>\</script\>

<script src="js/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="js/home.js"></script>

Here’s a brief overview of what I’m trying to do:
User Interface: I have an input field for the blog title and a text area for the article content. There's also an option to upload an image for the banner, which gets displayed at the top of the blog post.
Publishing the Post: When the user clicks the "Publish" button, I want to generate a unique document ID, gather the input data, and store it in Firestore under a new document in the "blogs" collection.
Problem: Despite setting up Firebase and Firestore correctly (or so I think), when I try to use the db variable to interact with Firestore, I get a ReferenceError: db is not defined.
However, when I try to publish a blog post,
I get the following error in the console:
Uncaught ReferenceError: db is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.\<anonymous\> (editor.js:66:9)

I'm not sure why this is happening, as I've correctly exported db from firebase.mjs and imported it in editor.js. I've tried including the Firebase SDK via <script> tags as well, but the error persists.
Could anyone point out what might be going wrong here?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Can you post a sandbox link so I can investigate? https://codesandbox.io/
How is db imported in editor.js? How is editor.js included in project?

@AntonijaŠimić Okie Mam
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/intelligent-goldwasser-glm4hm
I  also collabed u in the codesandbox mam
kindly help me, mam

Here are some suggestions that might help.
Since it is not clear from your question how is editor.js importing db and how is editor.js included in the project, I am assuming something is not right with those parts.
// firebase.js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDQaVM5xjFB-WB4IQXnupSvWOJSQdlrN00",
    authDomain: "bloggin-site-c4727.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "bloggin-site-c4727",
    storageBucket: "bloggin-site-c4727.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "170432646256",
    appId: "1:170432646256:web:f36807db85372e1956f8b5"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app); // notice the usage of the getFirestore() method

export { db };

I think you are trying to initialize Firebase using the older firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); syntax, which is part of the Firebase namespace approach (used in older versions of Firebase).
Secondly, do not forget to import db from the editor.js file
// editor.js
import { db } from './firebase.js';

// rest of your code

Thirdly, ensure that the firebase.js script is loaded BEFORE editor.js in your HTML file, especially if you are using <script> tags directly in the HTML. But I would recommend using type="module" since you are using import/export syntax.
<script type="module" src="js/firebase.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="js/editor.js"></script>

Here is more info about modules
Let me know if these tips have helped.

You are mixing "Web modular API" with "Web namespace API".

Firebase provides two API surfaces for Web apps:

JavaScript - namespaced. This is the JavaScript interface that
Firebase maintained for many years and is familiar to Web developers
with older Firebase apps. Because the namespaced API does not benefit
from ongoing new feature support, most new apps should instead adopt
the modular API.
JavaScript - modular. This SDK is based on a modular
approach that provides reduced SDK size and greater efficiency with
modern JavaScript build tools such as webpack or Rollup.


You can read more at Understand Firebase for Web
Now the issue in you firebase.jsm file is that you are importing modular API, but using namespace API properties in the file. Make the following changes(going through with modular API as it is the better choice):
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection } from "firebase/firestore"

const firebaseConfig = {
//firebaseconfig
}
const collectionName = "blogs"
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app)
export const blogsCollection = collection(db,collectionName)

Now you can use the blogsCollection instance to interact with the collection. You can visit the following link, to learn how to interact with the modular API: Get started with Cloud Firestore.
